# OpenAi Api request with proxy

Tags: python, proxy, openai-api

`I need to make a request for OpenAi by proxy.
Proxy - IPv4
Python error:
407 Proxy Authentication Required
Access to requested resource disallowed by administrator or you need valid username/password to use this resource

My code

```
import config
from openai import OpenAI

proxies = 
{
    'https': 'http://M0k0EN:ZSNkKy@95.164.128.235:9943'
}

client = OpenAI
(
    api_key=config.api_key,
    base_url=proxies.get('https'),
)
completion = client.completions.create
(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
    prompt="Say this is a test",
    max_tokens=7,
    temperature=0
)

print(completion.choices[0].text)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. create .env in your project directory

```
    OPENAI_API_KEY=your api key
    OPENAI_PROXY_URL=http://127.0.0.1:1080
```

2. invoke api

```
import httpx
from openai import OpenAI
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

proxy_url = os.environ.get("OPENAI_PROXY_URL")

client = OpenAI() if proxy_url is None or proxy_url == "" else OpenAI(http_client=httpx.Client(proxy=proxy_url))


completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[
        {"role": "system",
         "content": "You are a poetic assistant, skilled in explaining complex programming concepts with creative flair."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Compose a poem that explains the concept of recursion in programming."}
    ]
)

print(completion.choices[0].message)
```

Answer (score 1):

The OpenAI Python client doesn't directly support proxy configuration. You'll need to use the requests library to configure the proxy.

The base_url parameter is not intended for proxy settings. It's typically used to set a different API endpoint (if OpenAI provides alternative endpoints in the future).
You are using an HTTP proxy (http://) for HTTPS requests. Ensure that your proxy supports HTTPS traffic.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to use a proxy with the OpenAI API using requests:

```
import config
import openai
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

# Configure your proxy
proxy = "http://95.164.128.235:9943"
proxy_auth = HTTPProxyAuth('M0k0EN', 'ZSNkKy')

# Configure a session to use the proxy
session = requests.Session()
session.proxies = {'http': proxy, 'https': proxy}
session.auth = proxy_auth

# Tell OpenAI to use this session
openai.api_base = 'https://api.openai.com/v1'
openai.organization = 'your-organization-id'  # if you have an organization ID
openai.api_key = config.api_key
openai.session = session

try:
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
        prompt="Say this is a test",
        max_tokens=7,
        temperature=0
    )
    print(response.choices[0].text)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
```

Comment: I have the error
This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data.